# How to check alert message in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, testing, alert

I have a code which has 3 inputs and after providing input submit action happened which invokes api call and gives response in alert form. Now i dont know how to get the alert in react testing library.

When i tried with

```
window. alert=jest.fn() 
    expect(global.alert).tohavebeencalled()
```

I got this error

```
Expected call >= 1
Received call = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer now, I had to add await wait
after submit action

```
await waitFor(() =>expect(window.alert).toHave
```